# Different screen sizes issue?

Tags: android, flutter

how to set the margins and other values for the layout to get your layout perfect for every screen sized devices .....in bigger screen it worked fine but when I used to run on small screens it overflows the views how to fix it please any solutions for that thank you.**size**

Comment: actually i am using flutter

Comment: check this https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434 and this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977841/6919963) which answers exactly to it.

Comment: yes it does,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaQuery.of(context)` is what you're looking for, which returns a [MediaQueryData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery/data.html) that has all information about your phone width, height, padding , etc.

```
MediaQueryData _queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _height = _queryData.size.height;
    _width = _queryData.size.width;
    _heightPadding = _height - ((_queryData.padding.top + _queryData.padding.bottom));
    _widthPadding = _width - (_queryData.padding.left + _queryData.padding.right) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `SDP - a scalable size unit` library: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

I am using it in my projects and it works very well.

Edit: Now I see that you use flutter, the library I've recommended is for java/kotlin.